# Authentication in ADFS with Web Service

Tags: c#, web-services, adfs, wif, adfs2.0

I have developed the test application in which I have added .asmx file for ADFS authentication, after authentication, it would redirect to my original already developed web application. the common code is shown below

```
var stsEndpoint = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EndPoint"];
var relayPartyUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RelayPartyUri"];
EndpointAddress epoint = new EndpointAddress(stsEndpoint);

using (var factory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(new UserNameWSTrustBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential), epoint) { TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13 })
{
    if (factory.Credentials != null)
    {
        factory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = @"Domain\" + userName;
        factory.Credentials.UserName.Password = password;
    }
    var rst = new RequestSecurityToken
    {
        RequestType = WSTrust13Constants.RequestTypes.Issue,
        AppliesTo = new EndpointReference(relayPartyUri),
        KeyType = WSTrust13Constants.KeyTypes.Bearer
    };
    var channel = factory.CreateChannel();
    var token = channel.Issue(rst);
    var genericToken = token as GenericXmlSecurityToken;
    ...
}
...
```

The line **var token = channel.Issue(rst);** throws error

```
Error is ID3082: The request scope is not valid or is unsupported
```

Also, I am not sure which URI I should use for RelyingPartyURI

- the service URL which I am using for ADFS authentication. or
- the URL of my already developed web application

Please help.

Comment: Did you found the solution for this ? Was that the relayUri the issue ? Thanks in advance

Comment: you need to add user on ADFS user management (on server)

Answer (score 0):

relayPartyUri is the unique identifier for your app.